# Change the color of a node or an edge

Tags: python, networkx

I want to redraw a Graph g with only the color of a node or edge changed.
How do I do that?

Comment: The documentation says we can do H.add_edge(1,2,color='red')
but I get an error that color is not a valid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of networkx is too old.

try

```
$ easy_install networkx
```

to get the current version